# Connection to Hadoop Cluster From AWS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to our hadoop cluster from AWS instance ( where hadoop is not installed) to tranfser some files. However the following code is not working..

```
   System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.addResource(coreSite);
    configuration.addResource(hdfsSite);
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(user, keytabPath);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
```

The FileSystem object still points to the local AWS path only. I am using the `core-site.xml` , `hdfs-site.xml` , `.keytab` , `krb5.conf` and batchId as user of that particular cluster. Can someone give me some pointers for this.
Thanks.

**PS : I have tried to run this code in Windows environment too and its not working. SO environment issues can be ruled out.**

Comment: Try providing the property "fs.default.name" to the configuration of hadoop.It should work.

Comment: i think its already present in core-site.xml. fs.defaultFS.